# trying to install angular-chartist.js via bower.json

Tags: angularjs, node.js, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio to develop my angular js application and I have run into a problem.
A package I wish to install doesn't support **bower** anymore, instead it uses **npm**. On the readme it says that I should add:

```
"resolvers": [
    "bower-npm-resolver"
]
```

To the **.bowerrc** file, which I have done.

I have also updated my **npm** to the latest by running this command:

> npm install -g npm

and then I did the same for **bower-npm-resolver**:

> npm install -g bower-npm-resolver

All installed fine.
When I try to save my **bower.json** file, Visual Studio throws this error:

> MODULE_NOT_FOUND Cannot find module 'bower-npm-resolver'

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Instead of global install with

    npm install -g bower-npm-resolver

try a local install

    npm install bower-npm-resolver

Comment: how do I do that with visual studio? If I use cmd and navigate to my project directory, it won't use my wwwroot/lib directory will it?

Comment: in the package manager console cd to your project directory and run the command npm install bower-npm-resolver that will install it to the project. I don't know 100% this will solve your issue but I have had issues with some plugins when I installed global instead of local